# Python regex fetch the date form log file

Tags: python, regex

I want to fetch the date from the standard vsftp log file, the file is as below:

```
Fri Sep  1 15:43:46 2017 1 ::ffff:172.18.1.168 14848 /IT_inventory.xls b _ i r user01 ftp 0 * c
```

I tried to use regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
    with open("/var/log/xferlog") as log:
        for line in log:
            pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+) (\w+)')
            match = pattern.search(line)
            print match.group(1)
            print match.group(2)
```

The code can fetch day and month ( group(1) = Fri, group(2) = Sep ) correctly.

But I want to fetch the date(1), so I change the pattern:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+) (\w+) (\d+)')
        match = pattern.search(line)
        print match.group(1)
        print match.group(2)
        print match.group(3)
```

But the output change to 46, 2017, 1 ( group(1) = 46, group(2) = 2017, group(3) = 1 )

If I set up line manually.

```
line = "Fri Sep 1 15:43:46 2017 1 ::ffff:172.18.1.168 14848 /IT_inventory.xls b _ i r user01 ftp 0 * c"

pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+) (\w+) (\d+)')
match = pattern.search(line)
print match.group(1)
print match.group(2)
print match.group(3)
```

Then I can get what I want.

group(1)=Fri, group(2)=Sep, group(3)=1

Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re

s = "Fri Sep  1 15:43:46 2017 1 ::ffff:172.18.1.168 14848 /IT_inventory.xls b _ i r user01 ftp 0 * c"

data = re.findall("^\w+\s\w+", s)[0].split()
```

Output:

```
['Fri', 'Sep']
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It worked. But I am still very curious. Do you know why I will get the wired result if I read the file by syntax "with"?